# Codable enum with default case in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift4, codable

I have defined an `enum` as follows:

```
enum Type: String, Codable {
    case text = "text"
    case image = "image"
    case document = "document"
    case profile = "profile"
    case sign = "sign"
    case inputDate = "input_date"
    case inputText = "input_text"
    case inputNumber = "input_number"
    case inputOption = "input_option"

    case unknown
}
```

that maps a JSON string property.
The automatic serialization and deserialization works fine, but I found that if a different string is encountered, the deserialization fails.

Is it possible to define an `unknown` case that maps any other available case?

This can be very useful, since this data comes from a RESTFul API that, maybe, can change in the future.

Comment: You could declare the variable of your `Type` to be an optional.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I already tried this solution, but it doesn't work. I have an error during the deserialization.

Comment: Can you show some more of your code?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

You can extend your `Codable` Type and assign a default value in case of failure:

```
enum Type: String {
    case text,
         image,
         document,
         profile,
         sign,
         inputDate = "input_date",
         inputText = "input_text" ,
         inputNumber = "input_number",
         inputOption = "input_option",
         unknown
}
extension Type: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = try Type(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self)) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

---

edit/update:

**Xcode 11.2 • Swift 5.1 or later**

Create a protocol that defaults to last case of a `CaseIterable & Decodable` enumeration:

```
protocol CaseIterableDefaultsLast: Decodable & CaseIterable & RawRepresentable
where RawValue: Decodable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection { }

extension CaseIterableDefaultsLast {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = try Self(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self)) ?? Self.allCases.last!
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
enum Type: String, CaseIterableDefaultsLast {
    case text, image, document, profile, sign, inputDate = "input_date", inputText = "input_text" , inputNumber = "input_number", inputOption = "input_option", unknown
}
```

---

```
let types = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Type].self , from: Data(#"["text","image","sound"]"#.utf8))  // [text, image, unknown]
```

Comment: Slightly more generic if you're using this frequently. Replace try Type with try type(of: self).init

Comment: @Daniel is there any way to make a fully generic CodableWithUnknown protocol or something like that?

Comment: Downvoter a comment explaining the reason of it would be appreciated and would allow me to fix and/or improve what’s wrong with my answer. A downvote without a reason makes no sense

Answer (score 16):

You can drop the raw type for your `Type` and make **unknown** case that handles associated value. But this comes at a cost. You somehow need the raw values for your cases. Inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732126/3687801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47653647/3687801) SO answers I came up with this elegant solution to your problem.

To be able to store the **raw values**, we will maintain another enum, but as private:

```
enum Type {
    case text
    case image
    case document
    case profile
    case sign
    case inputDate
    case inputText
    case inputNumber
    case inputOption
    case unknown(String)

    // Make this private
    private enum RawValues: String, Codable {
        case text = "text"
        case image = "image"
        case document = "document"
        case profile = "profile"
        case sign = "sign"
        case inputDate = "input_date"
        case inputText = "input_text"
        case inputNumber = "input_number"
        case inputOption = "input_option"
        // No such case here for the unknowns
    }
}
```

Move the `encoding` & `decoding` part to extensions:

### Decodable part:

```
extension Type: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        // As you already know your RawValues is String actually, you decode String here
        let stringForRawValues = try container.decode(String.self) 
        // This is the trick here...
        switch stringForRawValues { 
        // Now You can switch over this String with cases from RawValues since it is String
        case RawValues.text.rawValue:
            self = .text
        case RawValues.image.rawValue:
            self = .image
        case RawValues.document.rawValue:
            self = .document
        case RawValues.profile.rawValue:
            self = .profile
        case RawValues.sign.rawValue:
            self = .sign
        case RawValues.inputDate.rawValue:
            self = .inputDate
        case RawValues.inputText.rawValue:
            self = .inputText
        case RawValues.inputNumber.rawValue:
            self = .inputNumber
        case RawValues.inputOption.rawValue:
            self = .inputOption

        // Now handle all unknown types. You just pass the String to Type's unknown case. 
        // And this is true for every other unknowns that aren't defined in your RawValues
        default: 
            self = .unknown(stringForRawValues)
        }
    }
}
```

### Encodable part:

```
extension Type: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .text:
            try container.encode(RawValues.text)
        case .image:
            try container.encode(RawValues.image)
        case .document:
            try container.encode(RawValues.document)
        case .profile:
            try container.encode(RawValues.profile)
        case .sign:
            try container.encode(RawValues.sign)
        case .inputDate:
            try container.encode(RawValues.inputDate)
        case .inputText:
            try container.encode(RawValues.inputText)
        case .inputNumber:
            try container.encode(RawValues.inputNumber)
        case .inputOption:
            try container.encode(RawValues.inputOption)

        case .unknown(let string): 
            // You get the actual String here from the associated value and just encode it
            try container.encode(string)
        }
    }
}
```

### Examples:

I just wrapped it in a container structure(because we'll be using JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder) as:

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let type: Type
}
```

**For values other than unknown case:**

```
let rootObject = Root(type: Type.document)
do {
    let encodedRoot = try JSONEncoder().encode(rootObject)
    do {
        let decodedRoot = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: encodedRoot)
        print(decodedRoot.type) // document
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**For values with unknown case:**

```
let rootObject = Root(type: Type.unknown("new type"))
do {
    let encodedRoot = try JSONEncoder().encode(rootObject)
    do {
        let decodedRoot = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: encodedRoot)
        print(decodedRoot.type) // unknown("new type")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

> I put the example with local objects. You can try with your REST API response.

Answer (score 9):

```
enum Type: String, Codable, Equatable {
    case image
    case document
    case unknown

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let rawValue = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) else {
            self = .unknown
            return
        }
        self = Type(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an explanation

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative based on [nayem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3687801/nayem)'s answer that offers a slightly more streamlined syntax by using optional binding of the inner `RawValues` initialization:

```
enum MyEnum: Codable {

    case a, b, c
    case other(name: String)

    private enum RawValue: String, Codable {

        case a = "a"
        case b = "b"
        case c = "c"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let decodedString = try container.decode(String.self)

        if let value = RawValue(rawValue: decodedString) {
            switch value {
            case .a:
                self = .a
            case .b:
                self = .b
            case .c:
                self = .c
            }
        } else {
            self = .other(name: decodedString)
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        switch self {
        case .a:
            try container.encode(RawValue.a)
        case .b:
            try container.encode(RawValue.b)
        case .c:
            try container.encode(RawValue.c)
        case .other(let name):
            try container.encode(name)
        }
    }
}
```

If you are certain that all your existing enum case names match the underlying string values they represent, you could streamline `RawValue` to:

```
private enum RawValue: String, Codable {

    case a, b, c
}
```

...and `encode(to:)` to:

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

    if let rawValue = RawValue(rawValue: String(describing: self)) {
        try container.encode(rawValue)
    } else if case .other(let name) = self {
        try container.encode(name)
    }
}
```

Here's a practical example of using this, e.g., you want to model `SomeValue` that has a property you want to model as an enum:

```
struct SomeValue: Codable {

    enum MyEnum: Codable {

        case a, b, c
        case other(name: String)

        private enum RawValue: String, Codable {

            case a = "a"
            case b = "b"
            case c = "letter_c"
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let decodedString = try container.decode(String.self)

            if let value = RawValue(rawValue: decodedString) {
                switch value {
                case .a:
                    self = .a
                case .b:
                    self = .b
                case .c:
                    self = .c
                }
            } else {
                self = .other(name: decodedString)
            }
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

            switch self {
            case .a:
                try container.encode(RawValue.a)
            case .b:
                try container.encode(RawValue.b)
            case .c:
                try container.encode(RawValue.c)
            case .other(let name):
                try container.encode(name)
            }
        }
    }

}

let jsonData = """
[
    { "value": "a" },
    { "value": "letter_c" },
    { "value": "c" },
    { "value": "Other value" }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

if let values = try? decoder.decode([SomeValue].self, from: jsonData) {
    values.forEach { print($0.value) }

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()

    if let encodedJson = try? encoder.encode(values) {
        print(String(data: encodedJson, encoding: .utf8)!)
    }
}


/* Prints:
 a
 c
 other(name: "c")
 other(name: "Other value")
 [{"value":"a"},{"value":"letter_c"},{"value":"c"},{"value":"Other value"}]
 */
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's start with a test case. We expect this to pass:

```
    func testCodableEnumWithUnknown() throws {
        enum Fruit: String, Decodable, CodableEnumWithUnknown {
            case banana
            case apple

            case unknown
        }
        struct Container: Decodable {
            let fruit: Fruit
        }
        let data = #"{"fruit": "orange"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!
        let val = try JSONDecoder().decode(Container.self, from: data)
        XCTAssert(val.fruit == .unknown)
    }
```

Our protocol `CodableEnumWithUnknown` denotes the support of the `unknown` case that should be used by the decoder if an unknown value arises in the data.

And then the solution:

```
public protocol CodableEnumWithUnknown: Codable, RawRepresentable {
    static var unknown: Self { get }
}

public extension CodableEnumWithUnknown where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = (try? Self(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self))) ?? Self.unknown
    }
}
```

The trick is make your enum implement with the `CodableEnumWithUnknown` protocol and add the `unknown` case.

I favor this solution above using the `.allCases.last!` implementation mentioned in other posts, because i find them a bit brittle, as they are not typechecked by the compiler.

Comment: This is better and more common. And `Self.RawValue == String` could be `Self.RawValue : Decodable`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement the `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` initializer and check for a valid value:

```
struct SomeStruct: Codable {

    enum SomeType: String, Codable {
        case text
        case image
        case document
        case profile
        case sign
        case inputDate = "input_date"
        case inputText = "input_text"
        case inputNumber = "input_number"
        case inputOption = "input_option"

        case unknown
    }

    var someType: SomeType

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        someType = (try? values.decode(SomeType.self, forKey: .someType)) ?? .unknown
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@LeoDabus thanks for your answers. I modified them a bit to make a protocol for String enums that seems to work for me:

```
protocol CodableWithUnknown: Codable {}
extension CodableWithUnknown where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            try self = Self(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self))!
        } catch {
            if let unknown = Self(rawValue: "unknown") {
                self = unknown
            } else {
                throw error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt force unwrap and or use a do catch there. If you want to constrain the enumeration type to String  you can do something like: `protocol CaseIterableDefaultsLast: Codable & CaseIterable { }
extension CaseIterableDefaultsLast where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String, Self.AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = try Self(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self)) ?? Self.allCases.last!
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Add this extension and set `YourEnumName` .

```
extension <#YourEnumName#>: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self = try <#YourEnumName#>(rawValue: decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self)) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the following method will decode all types of enums with RawValue of type Decodable (Int, String, ..) and returns nil if it fails. This will prevent crashes caused by non-existent raw values inside the JSON response.

#### Definition:

```swift
extension Decodable {
    static func decode<T: RawRepresentable, R, K: CodingKey>(rawValue _: R.Type, forKey key: K, decoder: Decoder) throws -> T? where T.RawValue == R, R: Decodable {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: K.self)
        guard let rawValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(R.self, forKey: key) else { return nil }
        return T(rawValue: rawValue)
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```swift
enum Status: Int, Decodable {
        case active = 1
        case disabled = 2
    }
    
    struct Model: Decodable {
        let id: String
        let status: Status?
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
            status = try .decode(rawValue: Int.self, forKey: .status, decoder: decoder)
        }
    }

// status: -1 reutrns nil
// status:  2 returns .disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to encode / decode
(this snippet supports Int an String RawValue type enums, but can be easy extended to fit other types)

```
extension NSCoder {
    
    func encodeEnum<T: RawRepresentable>(_ value: T?, forKey key: String) {
        guard let rawValue = value?.rawValue else {
            return
        }
        if let s = rawValue as? String {
            encode(s, forKey: key)
        } else if let i = rawValue as? Int {
            encode(i, forKey: key)
        } else {
            assert(false, "Unsupported type")
        }
    }
    
    func decodeEnum<T: RawRepresentable>(forKey key: String, defaultValue: T) -> T {
        if let s = decodeObject(forKey: key) as? String, s is T.RawValue {
            return T(rawValue: s as! T.RawValue) ?? defaultValue
        } else {
            let i = decodeInteger(forKey: key)
            if i is T.RawValue {
                return T(rawValue: i as! T.RawValue) ?? defaultValue
            }
        }
        return defaultValue
    }
    
}
```

than use it

```
// encode
coder.encodeEnum(source, forKey: "source")
// decode
source = coder.decodeEnum(forKey: "source", defaultValue: Source.home)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid decoding failure in case of wrong data type in JSON.

```
extension Type: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        do {
            let rawValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RawValue.self)
            self = Type(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .unknown
        } catch {
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

or in case where `RawValue` is `String`

```
extension Type: Decodable {

    init(from decoder: Decoder) {
        let rawValue = (try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)) ?? "unknown"
        self = Type(rawValue: rawValue) ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

For example: `{"foo": "image", "bar": "cake", "baz": 42}` -> `["foo": .image, "bar": .unknown, "baz": .unknown]`

Answer (score 0):

## Handling Unknown Enum Cases in Swift with Codable

```
protocol UnknownCodable: RawRepresentable, Codable where RawValue: Codable {
    static var unknown: Self { get }
}

extension UnknownCodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let decodedValue = try container.decode(RawValue.self)
        self = Self(rawValue: decodedValue) ?? Self.unknown
    }
}
```

### Usage example

```
enum Type: String, UnknownCodable {
    case text
    case image
    case document
    case unknown
}

let types = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Type].self , from: Data(#"["text","image","sound"]"#.utf8))

print(types) // [text, image, unknown]
```